# Variable value gets printed with heredoc execution

Tags: variable, here-document

While in `/var/www/html` I executed the following `cat` heredocument which serves as a **maker** - It makes the file `/opt/dwa.sh` which includes a function and a MYSQL heredocument.

```
cat <<-"DWA_INSTALL" > /opt/dwa.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    DWA() {
        test='test'

        read domain
        cp -rv /var/www/html/${domain} /var/www/html/${test}
        sed -i 's/${domain}/${test}'/g /var/www/html/test/wp-config.php
        sed -i 's/${domain}/${test}'/g /var/www/html/test/wp-config.php
        mysql --force -u root -p <<-MYSQL
            CREATE user '${test}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${psw}';
            CREATE database ${test};
            GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${test}.* TO ${test}@localhost;
        MYSQL
    }
    DWA
DWA_INSTALL
```

After making the file in execution, I  executed the file itself which contains the function, passing a `${domain}` argument to `read`.

Let's assume that this argument was:

```
example.com
```

### My problem

For testing purposes, I then rexecuted the `cat` heredocument maker, but now, instead getting this content inside `dwa.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
    DWA() {
        test='test'

        read domain
        cp -rv /var/www/html/${domain} /var/www/html/${test}
        sed -i 's/${domain}/${test}'/g /var/www/html/test/wp-config.php
        sed -i 's/${domain}/${test}'/g /var/www/html/test/wp-config.php
        mysql --force -u root -p <<-MYSQL
            CREATE user '${test}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${psw}';
            CREATE database ${test};
            GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${test}.* TO ${test}@localhost;
        MYSQL
    }
DWA
```

I got this, inside it:

```
    html/example.com/#!/bin/bash
    html/example.com/html/example.com/DWA() {
        html/example.com/test='test'
        html/example.com/
        html/example.com/read domain
        html/example.com/cp -rv /var/www/html/${domain} /var/www/html/${test}
        html/example.com/sed -i 's/${domain}/${test}'/g /var/www/html/test/wp-config.php
        html/example.com/sed -i 's/${domain}/${test}'/g /var/www/html/test/wp-config.php
        html/example.com/mysql --force -u root -p <<-MYSQL
            html/example.com/CREATE user '${test}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${psw}';
            html/example.com/CREATE database ${test};
            html/example.com/GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${test}.* TO ${test}@localhost;
        html/example.com/MYSQL
    html/example.com/}
html/example.com/DWA
```

### My question

From where these `html/example.com` strings come from? I have a feeling it has to do with `read` somehow, like it is some variable's value got "stuck" in the memory, but I don't know how to track down the variable by it's value and have no clue how to find out the source of these strings.

I tried to do `domain=''` and re-execute the `cat` heredocument again, but still the same result comes out. Given the `cat` heredocument doesn't not allow variable expansion due to double quotes ("EOT"), I feel even weirder with this.

I am quite new to Bash and don't have much experience working with variables (was never really part of the courses I took). Maybe you can advice.

### Update --- I solved the problem without understanding how:

After executing in console `exec bash`, I tried to repeat the regular pattern of running `DWA_INSTALL` and this time the file was created without the problem of the `html/example.com`. I don't know why, but it helped.

Comment: So, you ran the `cat <<-"DWA_INSTALL"` command twice, and got different output? Can you repeat that? Produce a minimal example illustrating the issue?

Comment: I ran it a few times actually. I don't know what went wrong in the middle. I am looking for any tip, any direction, that will help me understand what can cause the output I get now, each time I execute `cat <<-"DWA_INSTALL"`.

Comment: (1) I’m confused. You say you have done this several times.  You describe three actions: (A) the `cat`, (B) running the script, and (C) looking at the script.  Have you ever done A and then C without doing B?  Does the file still have `html/example.com/` on every line?  If so, it has nothing to do with the fact that you provided an input of `example.com` in step B.  If not, ***explain** what you have done **better**.* … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) Try this: `cat <<- "EOF"` (without redirecting output), then type some random lines, and then `EOF`. Include in the input at least one line starting with each of these strings: (i) a letter, (ii) a `#`, (iii) a `}`, (iv) a space, (v) a tab, and (vi) two tabs. Post the output. (3) Do you have a file or directory called `example.com`? Perhaps in an `html` directory? (4) Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: G-Man, I didn't try only A and C without B. Anyway, here's an update, after executing `exec bash` and than doing everything anew again --- I no longer had the problem described in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem without understanding how:

To clear all non environment variables (that is, all variables I myself declared), I ran in console:

```
exec bash
```

I hen tried to repeat the regular pattern of running `DWA_INSTALL` and this time the file was created without the problem of the `html/example.com` preliminaries.

I don't know why, but it helped; Please edit this answer with an explanation if you figured out what happened there.