# RAM cleanup operation without rebooting

Tags: bash, memory, variable, command-substitution, ram

Say I've stored different variables in RAM and did some actions with wired results when expanding variables and referencing files [as in this case](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408476/variable-value-gets-printed-with-heredoc-execution/408596).

What is the closest cleanup for all "artificial" RAM data without rebooting?

By artificial I mean to data that I've inserted manually into RAM such as declaring a variable (or that entered there as a result of whatever action I did). It is anything which didn't come naturally with the session (such as environment variables and inherited data).

Comment: Sorry in advance if I wrote something absurd, I did my best to describe myself there (I've edited). How would you "restart" a session, but without inheriting anything, and without `reboot`? I understand that `exec bash` and `bash` (subsession) aren't the ways.

Comment: Hmm, usually I'm using Windows10 Putty and doing `exit` closes Putty window (and then I need to manually open Putty and logging in anew and it's not very comfortable). It was most comfortable if I would using WSL with `ssh` but I usually use Putty from various reasons, for this. Thus, I need a way to restart `bash` in the way described above, but from within `bash` (if this is even possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Say I've stored different variables in RAM

No, you probably did not store any variable in RAM.

<sup>Unless you are using `/dev/mem` (see [mem(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html)) which is weird and requires root privileges.</sup>

The physical RAM is managed by the kernel (only). So the only way to store something in RAM is thru kernel code. Application code (even your [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell)) is running in [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)), each having its own [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) and using [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

The virtual address space is initialized at [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) time when a program is started (e.g. by your shell). It is destroyed when the process terminates (or gets reinitialized by any program doing a successful `execve`).

> What is the closest cleanup for all "artificial" RAM data without rebooting?

When the process having these "variables" (actually, they are [locations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address) in the virtual address space) terminates, the data is gone. If that process is a shell, you just need to terminate it (perhaps with the [`exit` shell builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html), or with [kill(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html), etc...), but you don't need to reboot.

To forget an environment variable set by the `export` [shell builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html), use the `unset` shell builtin. See also [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) and the [documentation of GNU `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html).

Maybe you want to use the [`batch` utility](https://linux.die.net/man/1/batch), perhaps with some [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). Maybe you just want to run a sub shell, or `bash` itself.

<sup>Perhaps running explicitly and wisely some `bash` could be very helpful. Did you try to run `bash` in your putty session? You can have several nested shells, and you could even run some *other* shell in your putty session, e.g. `fish`, ....</sup>

You should consider reading more about Linux programming (perhaps the old [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf); see also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html)). You may want to read more about [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), e.g. [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

Notice that the shell's state is *not* [persistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)). Of course, [startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) like `$HOME/.bashrc` contain commands that are run at start of every interactive shell (so you would put your "permanent" setting in that `$HOME/.bashrc` file as `export` commands).

Unix shells are ordinary programs (and you can change your login shell using [chsh(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html); you may need to have your new shell listed in `/etc/shells`, see [shells(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shells.5.html)). If you are not happy with `bash` you can use another shell (e.g. [zsh](http://zsh.org/) or [fish](http://fishshell.com/), etc...), and you can write your own shell (probably in some compiled language like Rust, C++, Ocaml, C, Go, ....). Your shell should just be some [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable.

<sup>(actually coding your own shell is a very useful exercise, and will help you to understand a lot of things; or at least study the source code of some existing shell, they are generally [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), perhaps as small as [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell))</sup>

You could also consider grouping your commands in some [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script), and run that script from your putty session (which is probably an interactive `bash`).